# Injecting config to ActiveDataProvider models

Tags: php, yii2

Is there a way to inject some config into DataProvider models?

for example I have this getter setter on an ActiveRecord

```
private $_uid
public function getUid(){
   return $this->_uid;
}
public function setUid($uid){
   $this->_uid = $uid;
}
```

The UID is not in the table and need to be set.

```
$model = new Model(['uid'=>5]);
```

or

```
$model = Model::findOne();
$model->uid = 5;
```

Currently I was doing it using the getModels()

```
$query = Model::find();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);

foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as &$models) {
    $models->uid = 5;
}
```

This works. 
However I was looking for more "clean" way to do this?

I was reading about Dependency Injection and it sound like I can do it with that, however I am new to the concept and unable to make it works.

Comment: You can override method `populate()` in model's ActiveQuery.

Comment: Nice Idea, I can create new property in the ActiveQuery and pass it into the model by iterating over the `parent::populate()`

Comment: If you can provide more information about uid nature, may be I can suggest better solution.

Comment: @SiZE the uid here is for indicating the user ID, in frontend I can use `Yii::$app->user->id` but on backend it need to set from other variable as `Yii::$app->user->id` is admin ID. My actual use case here is for backend gridview that simulated user-session view.

Comment: @SakuraiEvsa I've update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions to this problem could be:

```
Event::on(Model::className(), ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_FIND, function ($event) {
    $event->sender->uid = 5;
});
```

Updated:

@SakuraiEvs for this task

> the uid here is for indicating the user ID, in frontend I can use
>   Yii::$app->user->id but on backend it need to set from other variable
>   as Yii::$app->user->id is admin ID. My actual use case here is for
>   backend gridview that simulated user-session view.

I will prefer to fill models with custom values in cycle. Overriding `populate()` or using [PHP Callable Injection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html#php-callable-injection) is overhead.

Comment: So you mean that using my current approach is better than using [Dependency Injection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html#dependency-injection)?  Maybe you are right as the injector would need to traverse more process than simply using foreach. I guess I got misdirected by the novelty of it.